# dual of linear operator space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ and $V$ be finite dimensional vector spaces.

Let $L(U,V)$ be the space of linear maps $U\rightarrow V$.

Let $A \in L(U,V)^*$, i.e., the dual space of $L(U,V)$.

Is it true that $A : U^* \rightarrow V^*$?

---

**Edit: (from the comments)**

$L(U,V)^*$ is the dual space of $L(U,V)$.

I want to show that $L(U,V)^*$ is isomorphic to $L(U^*,V^*)$. I see that for each $A\in L(U^*,V^*)$ there is a map $l_A\in L(U,V)^*$ defined by $l_A(B)=\text{trace}(A^*B)$, where $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$.

Can we show that for each $l\in L(U,V)^*$ there is an $A$ such that $l=l_A$?

Comment: How do you define $L(U, V)^*$?

Comment: $L(U,V)^*$ is the dual space of $L(U,V)$

Comment: If by dual space of $L(U, V)$ you mean the set of (say) real linear functions from $L(U, V)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then of course $A\not \in L(U, V)^*$. As long as you know what the notation means answering this question should be fairly easy.

Comment: Yes, I meant $L(U,V)^*$ is the set of linear functions from $L(U,V)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I am wondering if $A \in L(U,V)^*$, what are the domain and codomain of $A$?

Comment: The domain of $A$ is $L(U, V)$ and the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$ according to your definition! That is, $A$ eats some function $f\colon U\to V$ and spits out a number $A(f)$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks. Rethinking my question some more, what I would like to do is the following.  Claim: $L(U,V)^*$ is isomorphic to $L(U^*,V^*)$.  Proof:  (i) For each $A \in L(U^*,V^*)$, there is $l_A \in L(U,V)^*$ defined as follows.  $l_A(B) = \text{trace}(A^* B)$ where $A^*: V\rightarrow U$ is the adjoint of $A$.  (ii) For each $l \in L(U,V)^*$ there is $A_l \in L(U^*,V^*)$.  Can we show this?

Comment: @user150113: It is not considered polite to leave large pieces of the question in the comments. You should edit your main post instead. I have done it for you this time, but in the future, please do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that $L(U, V)^*$ is isomorphic as a vector space to $L(U^*, V^*)$, because of obvious reasons: they have the same dimension.

The answer to your last question is affirmative. The linear map that you have defined between the two spaces is onto because of the [Riesz Representation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem). You have defined an inner product on $L(U^*, V^*)$ by setting $\langle A, B\rangle=\text{trace}(A^*B)$.